# xml error with Flash and PHP

Tags: php, xml, iis-7

I am trying to install a flash application on a local IIS 7 instance. The SWF file needs a php file named lex.php in order function properly. When running the swf in the browser it returns the error "XML Load Failed". When accessing the PHP file directly, it serves the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lex.php on line 1
```

The PHP file has an XML tag that when removed, allows it to work properly. Even though the PHP file works when removing the XML tag, the SWF will still not work. I have tried every suggestion I can find such as correcting permissions, adding the SWF MIME type as well as creating a handler mapping for PHP. I don't have much experience in configuring IIS so I hope this is an easy fix. thanks for any assistance

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-16"?><!-- generated by Visuwords(TM) xml.php ... visuwords.com --><!-- (c) 2007 dunnbypaul.net --><lex><lemma><identity>grindle</identity><associations><node index='1'><type>-</type><link>1:02639087</link><ss_type>1</ss_type><lex_filenum>05</lex_filenum><lex_filename>noun.animal</lex_filename><lex_id>00</lex_id><head_word></head_word><head_id></head_id><synset_offset>02639087</synset_offset><sense_number>1</sense_number><tag_cnt>0</tag_cnt></node></associations></lemma><seconds_to_execute>0.0056090354919434</seconds_to_execute></lex>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration setting.

By default this is set to `1` (evaluates to `TRUE`), which, according to PHP's document, will be broken by an XML declaration:

> If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can disable this
>   option in order to use
>
> `<?xml ?>`
>
> inline. Otherwise, you can print it with PHP, for example:
>
> `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>`.

Comment: Good catch! That helped.